# DataItem contains escaped HTML, how to render as actual HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, escaping, repeater

I have a repeater and am binding a `List<Event>` to it.

An `Event` has a property, `Details`, which contains some HTML mark-up in it.  I'm displaying that property inside my `<ItemTemplate>` as such:

```
<%# ((Event)Container.DataItem).Details %>
```

The html mark-up is escaped in the database.  So a detail might look like this in the database:

```
&lt;strong&gt;Blah blah blah&lt;/strong&gt;
```

After databinding, it looks like this on the page (but in the source, still matches what's in the database):

```
<strong>Blah blah blah</strong>
```

But what I need is for it to look like this:

**Blah blah blah**

I'm really at a loss for how to make that happen though, without going through the database and doing a massive find & replace, which isn't really an option since I'd also have to change the mechanism that inserts the data.

Comment: have you tried <%= ((Event)Container.DataItem).Details %>  instead?  I think the <%= will allow the html to be rendered.

Comment: It doesn't know what `Container` is when I switch to `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to convert back to regular Html.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(((Event)Container.DataItem).Details)
```

Comment: Wrong one. This isn't URL encoding.